# How to generate HTML elements on jQuery api call (SOLVED)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api

This is my code. I'm able to recive and display the data. However when displaying the data It's all displayed in one HTML-element, to clarify I get 9 titles in my $(".title"). Instead I would like to generate one title-element foreach API response.

```
//jQuery
var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
var queryURL = "https://api.edamam.com/search?q=mango&app_id=id&app_key=key";
console.log(queryURL);

// Grabbing API results
$.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then (function(response) {
        
        for(let i = 0;i< 9; i++){
        $(".title").append("Recipe: " + response.hits[i].recipe.label);
        $(".img").append("src", response.hits[i].recipe.image);
        $(".ingredients").append(response.hits[i].recipe.ingredientLines);
          
        }
  });
```

```
//HTML 
<body>
    <div class="card-body">
  <h1 class="title"></h1>
  <img class="img" />
  <p class="ingredients"></p>
</div>
</body>
```

**Solution** courtesy of @ChrisG.

```
//inside of function(response)
const $card = $('<div>').addClass("card-body").appendTo('body');
            $('<h1>').addClass('title').text("Recipe " + response.hits[i].recipe.label).appendTo($card);
$('<p>').addClass('ingredients').text("ingredients " + response.hits[i].recipe.ingredientLines).appendTo($card);
 var img = $('<img />').attr({
                    'id': 'myImage',
                    'src': response.hits[i].recipe.image,
                    'width': 250
                }).appendTo($card);
```

Comment: You're just appending text to a single element. You need to create a card div instead, fill it with content, then append it to `<body>`. Creating a new element and appending it works like this: `const $card = $('<div>').addClass("card-body").appendTo('body');` Next you can do `$('<h1>').addClass('title').text("Recipe" + ...).appendTo($card);` and so on

Comment: @ChrisG That's pretty much an answer :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But am I wrong to not post these as answers though? Is it official policy to rehash API docs in answers? Honest question.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Im having trouble with appending the image. I tried to use attr and append but it does not appear to show, any suggestions?

Comment: Please put the code you've tried into the question.

Comment: @ChrisG I have no idea what the official policy is for this situation, however in cases like this were the OP has a specific example and has shown effort I think providing an answer is absolutely acceptable.